# How to avoid additional space in tcbraster?

Tags: tcolorbox

I tried to generate some code for meetings. Therefore I want to name the participiants with ther institution and print them out in alphabetic order per institution. To achieve this I want to use tcbraster from `tcolorbox`. I have to iterate through my lists using `\@for` and fill the `tcolorbox`es with the content. This functions well. But within the tcbraster there is a small amount of space at the beginning of the first row and therefore I obtain one comln less than requested. If I reduce the width of the `tcbraster` to 97% of `\textwidth` it works. If I do tcbraster manually it works also. How can I avoid the small extra space that makes life so hard and the output not to be so nice.

Here is a minimal example and the generated output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[raster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lstdoc}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

\let\Institutionen\@empty

% Definition der Umgebungen
\newenvironment{Einladung}{\Einladungskopfsetzen}{}

\newcommand*{\ifundefined}[1]{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

%Listprocessing
\def\addtolist#1#2{%
    \expandafter\lst@lAddTo\csname #1\endcsname{#2,}
    \expandafter\lst@BubbleSort\csname #1\endcsname
}

\renewcommand{\ifinlist}[3]{\@for\next:=#1\do{\ifthenelse{\equal\next{\trim@spaces{#2}}}{#3}{\relax}}}

%\IfSubStr[*][number]{string}{stringA}{true}{false}
% Teilnehmerbefehle definieren
\def\teilnBearbeiten#1#2#3#4{
    \IfSubStr{\Institutionen}{#3} %%% Prï¿½fen, ob Institution in Liste bereits enthalten ist
        {   %%% Institution in Liste enthalten, tue nichts
        } 
        {   %%% Institution in Liste nicht enthalten, also in Liste aufnehmen
            \addtolist{Institutionen}{#3} 
            \expandafter\let\csname #3\endcsname\@empty
        }
    \addtolist{#3}{#1#2#3}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname #1#2#3\endcsname{\csname #4\endcsname{\trim@spaces{#1}, \trim@spaces{#2}}}
}

\def\teiln#1,#2,#3;{
\teilnBearbeiten{#1}{#2}{#3}{relax} % anstelle des relax kann ein Formatbefehl stehen z.B. 'uwave' aus 'ulem'
}

\newcommand{\Einladungskopfsetzen}{
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster equal height, size=small, colframe=red!50!black, colback=white!10!white, colbacktitle=black!40!white, toprule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, titlerule=0pt, arc=0pt]
    \@for\nextInstitution:=\Institutionen\do{
        \ifx\empty\nextInstitution\empty
        \else
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\nextInstitution]
            \edef\tempListe{\csname\nextInstitution\endcsname}
            \@for\nextEintrag:=\tempListe\do{
                \ifx \empty\nextEintrag\empty  
                \else
                  \csname\nextEintrag\endcsname\\
                \fi
            }
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \fi
    }
    \end{tcbraster}
}

\newcommand{\EinladungskopfsetzenOHNE}{
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster width=0.97\textwidth, raster columns=3, raster equal height, size=small, colframe=red!50!black, colback=white!10!white, colbacktitle=black!40!white, toprule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, titlerule=0pt, arc=0pt]
    \@for\nextInstitution:=\Institutionen\do{
        \ifx\empty\nextInstitution\empty
        \else
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\nextInstitution]
            \edef\tempListe{\csname\nextInstitution\endcsname}
            \@for\nextEintrag:=\tempListe\do{
                \ifx \empty\nextEintrag\empty  
                \else
                  \csname\nextEintrag\endcsname\\
                \fi
            }
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \fi
    }
    \end{tcbraster}
}

\begin{document}
    \teiln Name1,Vorname1,Institution1; 
    \teiln Name2,Vorname2,Institution1;
    \teiln Name3,Vorname3,Institution3;
    \teiln Name4,Vorname4,Institution4;
    \teiln Name5,Vorname5,Institution5;

 \section{tcbraster ohne  `raster width=0.97\textbackslash textwidth'}
    \begin{Einladung}
        Agenda
    \end{Einladung}

\section{tcbraster mit  `raster width=0.97\textbackslash textwidth'}

\EinladungskopfsetzenOHNE

\section{tcbraster ohne Schleifen}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster equal height, size=small, colframe=red!50!black, colback=white!10!white, colbacktitle=black!40!white, toprule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, titlerule=0pt, arc=0pt]
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

And here is the generated output:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You're missing multiple `%` characters in your `\do{...` parts

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple `%` characters missing in the `\do{`-- parts, causing stray white space (and horizontal shift), leading to a wrap over to the next line if there's not enough space left for a `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[raster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lstdoc}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\makeatletter

\let\Institutionen\@empty

% Definition der Umgebungen
\newenvironment{Einladung}{\Einladungskopfsetzen}{}

\newcommand*{\ifundefined}[1]{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

%Listprocessing
\def\addtolist#1#2{%
    \expandafter\lst@lAddTo\csname #1\endcsname{#2,}
    \expandafter\lst@BubbleSort\csname #1\endcsname
}

\renewcommand{\ifinlist}[3]{\@for\next:=#1\do{\ifthenelse{\equal\next{\trim@spaces{#2}}}{#3}{\relax}}}

%\IfSubStr[*][number]{string}{stringA}{true}{false}
% Teilnehmerbefehle definieren
\def\teilnBearbeiten#1#2#3#4{
    \IfSubStr{\Institutionen}{#3} %%% Prï¿½fen, ob Institution in Liste bereits enthalten ist
        {   %%% Institution in Liste enthalten, tue nichts
        } 
        {   %%% Institution in Liste nicht enthalten, also in Liste aufnehmen
            \addtolist{Institutionen}{#3} 
            \expandafter\let\csname #3\endcsname\@empty
        }
    \addtolist{#3}{#1#2#3}
    \expandafter\gdef\csname #1#2#3\endcsname{\csname #4\endcsname{\trim@spaces{#1}, \trim@spaces{#2}}}
}

\def\teiln#1,#2,#3;{%
\teilnBearbeiten{#1}{#2}{#3}{relax} % anstelle des relax kann ein Formatbefehl stehen z.B. 'uwave' aus 'ulem'
}

\newcommand{\Einladungskopfsetzen}{%
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster equal height, size=small, colframe=red!50!black, colback=white!10!white, colbacktitle=black!40!white, toprule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, titlerule=0pt, arc=0pt]
    \@for\nextInstitution:=\Institutionen\do{%
        \ifx\empty\nextInstitution\empty
        \else
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\nextInstitution]
            \edef\tempListe{\csname\nextInstitution\endcsname}
            \@for\nextEintrag:=\tempListe\do{
                \ifx \empty\nextEintrag\empty  
                \else
                  \csname\nextEintrag\endcsname\\
                \fi
            }
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \fi
    }
    \end{tcbraster}
}

\newcommand{\EinladungskopfsetzenOHNE}{%
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster width=0.97\textwidth, raster columns=3, raster equal height, size=small, colframe=red!50!black, colback=white!10!white, colbacktitle=black!40!white, toprule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, titlerule=0pt, arc=0pt]
    \@for\nextInstitution:=\Institutionen\do{%
        \ifx\empty\nextInstitution\empty
        \else
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\nextInstitution]
            \edef\tempListe{\csname\nextInstitution\endcsname}
            \@for\nextEintrag:=\tempListe\do{
                \ifx \empty\nextEintrag\empty  
                \else
                  \csname\nextEintrag\endcsname\\
                \fi
            }
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \fi
    }
    \end{tcbraster}
}

\begin{document}
    \teiln Name1,Vorname1,Institution1; 
    \teiln Name2,Vorname2,Institution1;
    \teiln Name3,Vorname3,Institution3;
    \teiln Name4,Vorname4,Institution4;
    \teiln Name5,Vorname5,Institution5;

 \section{tcbraster ohne  `raster width=0.97\textbackslash textwidth'}
    \begin{Einladung}
        Agenda
    \end{Einladung}

\section{tcbraster mit  `raster width=0.97\textbackslash textwidth'}

\EinladungskopfsetzenOHNE

\section{tcbraster ohne Schleifen}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, raster equal height, size=small, colframe=red!50!black, colback=white!10!white, colbacktitle=black!40!white, toprule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, titlerule=0pt, arc=0pt]
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[title=TITEL]
              Box Text
            \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Stealing my ordinary job? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I am the new egreg ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: _Thank you very much_. The answer is easy, but why does it work? White space at the end of line disturbes at the beginning of the line it does not.

Comment: @ORO: It's not really at the end of the line but between two raster boxes -- the white space shifts additionally the last box, but this is too wide now, such that `tcolorbox` places it in the next row

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: O.k. If I do not add the `%` after `\do{` I obtain additional white space that mix things up. If I add the `%` every thing is in order. But the `\do{` has only be followed by a line break and what is about the spaces at the beginning of the line before `\ifx\empty`? As you can see I am like a novice with respect to TeX/LaTeX internals.

Comment: @ORO: Sorry, forgot to answer your comment! At the beginning of a newline, `TeX` enters the `N` - state (see `TeX by Topic` for deeper explanation), in which any character with `catcode` `10` is ignored, e.g. spaces